# printing large font characters using ASCII values like diode screens

Tags: c

Hello I do not what type of this program called, but I will do my best to describe it.
I want to write a program preferably in C that prints using ASCII characters to print large characters similar to diodes signs

Eg.

Output:

#

#

#
#
#
#

for characters L

Comment: Go for it.  Ask a real question next time.

Answer (score 1):

On linux, the programs banner and figlet can do what you want. Look them up on google.